# How do I send a Django model and it's related (_set)s via Ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-models

How do I send a Django model and it's related (_set)s via Ajax?

```
class Zoo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    details = models.TextField(blank=True) # HUGE AMOUNT OF DATA
    animals_json = models.TextField(blank=True) # Information on what animals are in Zoo

class Animals(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    zoo = models.ForeignKey(Zoo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    animal_name = models.TextField(blank=True)


zoo = Zoo.objects.filter(pk=5)
animals = []
for animal in json.loads(zoo.animals_json):
    animals.append(Animals(zoo=zoo, animal_name=animal['name']))


# Now I have a Zoo model and a list of animals. 
# My Zoo model has a animal_set (RelatedManager) object
```

Now, I would like to send a JSON encoded Zoo via Ajax to front end. How do I do this? Option 1)

```
zoo_json = serializers.serialize('json', [zoo])
return HttpResposne(zoo_json)
```

This won't work because then I'm not sending any information about the animals. (Yes I realized it's encoded in the animals_json, but I want to just send clean objects via AJAX and not parse it with a front end loop). Something like this seems very messy as well because now the objects are seperate from one another:

```
zoo_json = serializers.serialize('json', [zoo])
animals_json = serializers.serialize('json', animals)
data_to_send_via_ajaz = {'zoo' : zoo_json, 'animals' : animals_json}
return HttpResposne(zoo_json)
```

My ideal object looks like this:

```
zoo_model_in_json_form [
    animal_model_in_json_form,
    animal_model_in_json_form,
    animal_model_in_json_form,
    ...
]

return HttpResposne(zoo_model_in_json_form)
```

This way I can loop through all the animals very easily. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use your own method of serializing the objects using [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) objects and finally using [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to dump the `dict` object as a string with response [content_type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.content_type) set to `application/json`.

**Solution**:

```
import json

zoo = Zoo.objects.filter(pk=5).first() # adding `first` call to get a single zoo
serialized_zoo_data = dict()

# serialize zoo with its animals nested in it
# Serialized zoo with animals:
# {
#   "id": 1,
#   "details": "blah blah",
#   "animals": [{
#       "id": 222,
#       "name": "Gorilla"   
#    }, {
#       "id": 11,
#       "name": "Camel"
#    }]
# }
if zoo is not None:
    # get all animals belonging to a `Zoo` object
    zoo_animals = zoo.animal_set.all()

    serialized_zoo_data["id"] = zoo.id
    serialized_zoo_data["details"] = zoo.details
    serialized_zoo_data["animals"] = []
    for animal in zoo_animals:
        animal = dict()
        animal["id"] = animal.id
        animal["name"] = animal.animal_name
        serialized_zoo_data["animals"].append(animal)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(serialized_zoo_data), content_type="application/json")
```